# Switch Cameras Surface Pro 4

Tags: wpf, camera, .net-4.5, directshow, leadtools-sdk

I have an application written using .Net 4.5 and WPF and mainly for use in Windows 10. In this application, I have created a custom window for capturing images and videos, using leadtools (directshow) to control the camera. Everything looks great with my camera on most devices that I have tried it on except the Surface Pro 4, and that is the device that we have bought multiple of for testing the application. If the tablet is moving while I try to set the selected camera, it takes a little over 10 seconds for the cameras to actually switch. The time doesn't change much (within a 10 milliseconds) whether the tablet is moving a little at the moment I tell it to switch cameras or if I shake the tablet wildly till the 10 seconds passes and the preview starts back up. Then, if I leave my Surface Pro 4 on its stand on my desk and tell it to switch cameras, it switches cameras in less than half a second. Has anyone else seen this problem? Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: If it is a programming question, you are supposed to add specific details/code. If it's a general software/hardware question, then you'd better off asking on SuperUser.

Comment: this does sounds like a product specific problem and one that only Microsoft might have an answer to, though I suspect they'll say it's "by design"

Comment: In case the problem was related to our toolkit, we could run some tests if you open a support case and send us more details. To do that, send full information to support@leadtools.com including which version of the toolkit you're using, what LEADTOOLS code is being called and how you're using it with WPF.